NoReverseMatch at /manager/addVehicle/ Reverse for 'addVehicle' not found. 'addVehicle' is not a valid view function or pattern name
I started my first project in django and am facing the following error.
Request Method:     GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/manager/addVehicle/
Django Version:     5.1.2
Exception Type:     NoReverseMatch
Exception Value:    

Reverse for 'addVehicle' not found. 'addVehicle' is not a valid view function or pattern name.

Exception Location:     C:\Users\\Documents\vehicle-share-system\.venv\Lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py, line 831, in _reverse_with_prefix
Raised during:  manager.views.addVehicle

this is my views.py folder
from django.shortcuts import render

# Create your views here.

def addVehicle(request):
    return render(request,'add_vehicle.html')

my add_vehicle.html file
`{% extends 'base.html'%}
{% block content %}


<h1>Add vehicle</h1>
<br/><br/>
<form method="POST" action= "{% url 'addVehicle' %}">
  {% csrf_token %}
  

  <div class="mb-3">
    <label for="Homelocation" class="form-label">Home location</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="HomeLocation" name="home_location">
  </div>
  <div class="mb-3">
    <label for="Model" class="form-label">Model</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Model" name="model" >
  </div>

  <div class="mb-3">
    <label for="Make" class="form-label">Make </label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="make" name="make">
  </div>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
</form>

{% endblock %}`

urls.py
from . import views
from reservations.models import Reservations
from reservations.models import vehicles

urlpatterns=[
    path('addVehicle/', views.addVehicle)
] 

I am getting the error even though the fn name in views file is the exact same. I have tried copy pasting the exact name and still don't know where i am going wrong. Any help will be greatly appreciated.
Project structure

You need to give your path a proper name:
urlpatterns = [
    #                                      🖟 name of the path
    path('addVehicle/', views.addVehicle, name='addVehicle')
]

here, if you are using app structure then just pass the url like below:
<form method="POST" action= "{% url 'appname:addVehicle' %}">

please also provide here the full code and project structure here in question will proper guide you on this. Thank you

got the following error when I changed the code to 
''' NoReverseMatch at /manager/addVehicle/
'appname' is not a registered namespace '''


appname means here mention your app name and try
